# IntelliJ typo suggestions with a single click

Tags: user-interface, intellij-idea, ide

Most UI when mouse control click will put the typo correction suggestions on the immediate menu. In IntellyJ you have to click two more times to get there. Alt + enter, gets you there with only one more step, but itself it is expensive to use as a shortcut (especially combined with following mouse operation).

Is it possible to configure IntellyJ to move the typo suggestions on the top, for the context menu for word with a spelling error?

Or alternatively, can I create a shortcut that directly pops the box with suggestions?